# How to fetch certain filenames using grep?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, grep

I have files like this in a certain directory:

```
my@unix:~/kys$ ls
address_modified_20130312.txt   customer_rows_full_20131202.txt
customer_full_20131201.txt      customer_rows_modified_20131202.txt
customer_modified_20131201.txt
my@unix:~/kys$
```

I want to use grep to fetch certain filenames which begin with a word "customer". I tried this

```
my@unix:~/kys$ ls | grep customer.*
customer_full_20131201.txt
customer_modified_20131201.txt
customer_rows_full_20131202.txt
customer_rows_modified_20131202.txt
my@unix:~/kys$
```

But this gives me these customer_rows.* files which I don't want. The correct result set is

```
customer_full_20131201.txt
customer_modified_20131201.txt
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep`

```
ls -1 | grep "^customer_[^r].*$"
```

Using the `find` command

```
find . \! -iname "customer_rows*"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
ls customer_[fm]*
```

or

```
ls customer_[^r]*
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep -v` to filter out what you don't want.

```
ls customer* | grep -v '^customer_rows'
```

Answer (score 0):

With Bash extended globbing, you could say

```
ls customer_!(rows)*
```

or, more likely, something like

```
for f in customer_!(rows)*; do
    : something with "$f"
done
```

With POSIX shell or traditional Bourne, you could say

```
for f in customer_*; do
    case $f in customer_rows* ) continue ;; esac
    : something with "$f"
done
```